# DB2 conditional import

Tags: sql, database, db2, data-import, db2-luw

I have two DB2 databases (Database1 and Database2) both containing a table called SubscriptionTable. Both tables contain user subscription related data and the columns of SubscriptionTable are the same in both databases.

Now I need to copy (and overwrite) data from Database1.SubscriptionTable to Database2.SubscriptionTable but only if the LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP column in Database2.SubscriptionTable is not greater than a specific date.

So in short I would like to overwrite subscription data in Database2.SubscriptionTable but only if the data was NOT modified after a specific date.

Could I use existing utility for this purpose, e.g. db2 import where I could also specify a condition (LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP < 'XXXX-XX-XX') for each row being overwritten ?

Comment: Are the databases linked to each other so you can solve this with a SQL query?

Comment: They are not connected, but it seems establishing a connection between the DB's would be the only way to solve this problem (apart from developing a custom utility that will copy the data). Thanks

Comment: The alternative would be to copy the entire table over and do the comparison locally.

Comment: See if the `INGEST` command with the `MERGE` statement could do what you want -- check out samples [in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0057198.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-5-2-4-59&lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

The DB2 `IMPORT` utility does not have the ability to ignore rows based on what is in them.

The "easiest" way to do this would be, as Gordon Linoff suggests in the comments, would be via federation, so Database1.SubscriptionTable is accessible from within Database2.

Alternatively, you could simply export the data from Database1 that meets your criteria:

```
-- Connect to Database1
export to data.del of del select * from SubscriptionTable 
                           where last_updated_timestamp > ...

-- Connect to Database2
import from data.del of del insert into SubscriptionTable ...
```

Comment: Exporting only data from Database1 that meets the criteria wouldn't work as the value of LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP column needs to be taken from Database2. 
So as you suggest DB2 Federation so that both databases would be accessible via SQL seems to be the only way in this case.

Comment: The alternative would be to export the entire table from database1, and import it into a temporary table in database2, and then use SQL (`MERGE`) to update SubscriptionTable from the temporary table in database2.